# Is it possible to dump my Oracle Database to rebuild it on another machine?

Tags: database, oracle

As the title asks, i have a complete oracle Xe11g database, that i have to export on my teacher machine in order to "show" it, i saw some examples of databases dumps all over the internet but i couldn't quite understand the process, is someone kind enough to explain me if a database dump can be rebuilt into another machine with the same oracle Xe11g ?
I have preserved the original sql queries files, but those are a little bit messy.

Comment: The easiest way to do this is from your client software. For example, SQL Developer is used by many developers; it is a product developed and maintained by Oracle itself, and it is freely available. It has GUI tools to make this process relatively trouble-free.

Comment: Essentially what it does is to automatically generate the CREATE TABLE, CREATE INDEX, INSERT etc. statements to be able to clone your database - instead of using your saved, but messy, SLQ query files; did you save all your INSERT statements, but also all the UPDATE and DELETE statements you ran later? Do you know which of those were committed and which were rolled back? etc. (I don't think a YES answer to the last question is possible; you should also have saved the ROLLBACK and COMMIT commands in your files, and know the exact sequence.)

Comment: ... and a question for you:  WHY ask here, and not ask your teacher? :-)

Comment: Due to the pandemic, we as students can't go at teacher's offices anymore, and we can only write important emails, this is not counted as "important or urgent" matter.

To answer @mathguy , yes i'm saving every single line of code i'm writing, including triggers and stored procedures, but the teacher said clearly "dump", without explaining how to do it.
Yes i am currently using SQL developer, and i have accepted every COMMIT request it popped up upon closing it, i suppose this is what you asked?

Comment: Yes, part of what I asked anyway. If you always committed every action you took, then if you saved all statements (and you know the exact order in which you executed them), then by executing exactly the same statements again, in the same order, you will get a clone of your DB. But, the other thing I suggested (rather than "asked") was to find the SQL Developer tools for cloning a DB - closer to the "dump" concept (rather than "recreate by following all the same steps again").

Answer (score 2):

As it is **11gXE**, a simple option is to use (the original) `export` and `import` utilities. Why not data pump? These two are simpler and will do the job.

Here's an example: I have user named `mike` which will "act" as if it was your user, in your XE database.

```
c:\Temp>exp system/pwd owner=mike file=mike.dmp log=mike_exp.log

Export: Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on ╚et Svi 14 20:56:52 2020

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.


Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
Export done in EE8MSWIN1250 character set and AL16UTF16 NCHAR character set
server uses AL32UTF8 character set (possible charset conversion)

About to export specified users ...
. exporting pre-schema procedural objects and actions
. exporting foreign function library names for user MIKE
. exporting PUBLIC type synonyms
. exporting private type synonyms
. exporting object type definitions for user MIKE
About to export MIKE's objects ...
. exporting database links
. exporting sequence numbers
. exporting cluster definitions
. about to export MIKE's tables via Conventional Path ...
. . exporting table                           TEST          0 rows exported
. exporting synonyms
. exporting views
. exporting stored procedures
. exporting operators
. exporting referential integrity constraints
. exporting triggers
. exporting indextypes
. exporting bitmap, functional and extensible indexes
. exporting posttables actions
. exporting materialized views
. exporting snapshot logs
. exporting job queues
. exporting refresh groups and children
. exporting dimensions
. exporting post-schema procedural objects and actions
. exporting statistics
Export terminated successfully without warnings.

c:\Temp>
```

I'll now drop it so that my database won't have `mike` any more, and that will "act" as if it was your teacher's XE database. You - or your teacher - will not do that.

```
c:\Temp>sqlplus sys/pwd as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on ╚et Svi 14 20:29:28 2020

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

SQL> drop user mike cascade;

User dropped.

SQL>
```

Now, you'd put the `mike.dmp` file to USB memory stick (or mail it to your teacher if it isn't too large). Teacher will first have to create user `mike` and then import your `mike.dmp` file.

---

This will your teacher do:

```
c:\Temp>sqlplus sys/pwd as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on ╚et Svi 14 20:50:20 2020

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

SQL> select tablespace_name from dba_tablespaces;

TABLESPACE_NAME
------------------------------
SYSTEM
SYSAUX
UNDOTBS1
TEMP
USERS

SQL> create user mike identified by lion
  2  default tablespace users
  3  temporary tablespace temp
  4  quota unlimited on users;

User created.

SQL> grant create session to mike;

Grant succeeded.

SQL>
```

Import:

```
c:\Temp>imp system/pwd file=mike.dmp full=y log=mike_imp.log

Import: Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on ╚et Svi 14 21:00:04 2020

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.


Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

Export file created by EXPORT:V11.02.00 via conventional path
import done in EE8MSWIN1250 character set and AL16UTF16 NCHAR character set
import server uses AL32UTF8 character set (possible charset conversion)
. importing SYSTEM's objects into SYSTEM
. importing MIKE's objects into MIKE
. . importing table                         "TEST"          0 rows imported
Import terminated successfully without warnings.

c:\Temp>
```

---

That's it; teacher how has your schema in their database, can connect as `mike` and review everything you've done.

Comment: Pretty comprehensive instructions. If I may add that if the objects being imported have custom tablespaces then these need to be pre-created. Suggest perhaps amending the answer to include these steps.

Comment: In real life, that would be an option. This is a school-oriented 11gXE, I somehow doubt that anyone created additional tablespaces. But - yes, thank you for the comment, @TenG.

Comment: Oh my god, this is so perfect ! Thank you , and yes my teacher is the Database exam teacher, he knows how to import i hope :D , otherwise i'll tell him this way of importing dumps!

Answer (score 1):

If the target host has oracle installed you can import

the dump

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sutil/oracle-data-pump.html#GUID-501A9908-BCC5-434C-8853-9A6096766B5A